# c# BufferedSize not working properly?

Tags: c#

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream("test",FileMode.Create);
BufferedStream buff = new BufferedStream(stream, 8);
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(buff);
writer.Write(1);
writer.Write(2);
writer.Write(3);
Console.WriteLine(buff.Length);
```

As I understand content is flushed when it reaches bufer size in this code 8 bytes. 
So why `buff.Length` returns 12 and why data appears in file only if I explicit call `Dispose/Close`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BufferedStream` works fine - it doesn't flush: `stream.Length` is `8` until it is closed; i.e.

```
// note these should really use "using" statements of similar
FileStream stream = new FileStream("test", FileMode.Create);
BufferedStream buff = new BufferedStream(stream, 8);
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(buff);
writer.Write(1);
writer.Write(2);
writer.Write(3);
Console.WriteLine(stream.Length); // 8
Console.WriteLine(buff.Length); // 12
```

The reason that `buff.Length` is `12` is because *that is the length of the underlying stream*. Basically, `BufferedStream` just re-exposes the stream underneath, and to ensure it doesn't miss the buffered data it adds a `Flush()` if there is buffered data:

```
public override long Length
{
    get
    {
        this.EnsureNotClosed();
        if (this._writePos > 0)
        {
            this.FlushWrite();
        }
        return this._stream.Length;
    }
}
```

Hence:

```
Console.WriteLine(stream.Length); // 8
Console.WriteLine(buff.Length); // 12
Console.WriteLine(stream.Length); // 12
```

Note that the `FileStream` can have its own buffering too

Answer (score 0):

The `BufferedStream` will write the contents of its buffer to the inner `FileStream` after `8` bytes.

However, the `FileStream` itself has its own buffering and will write content less frequently.